# Weird Behaviour in a Python List

Tags: python, list, text, set

Having trouble completely cleaning a list of words. I've gone to lengths using the following to strip out special characters, but a subsequent loop breaks when it encounters a list item of the form: `"['"` - see attached screenshot. I am unable to strip this gremlin out somehow... advice appreciated. thanks.

```py
df.to_csv('bodies', encoding='utf-8')
uni = pd.read_csv('bodies', index_col = [0], encoding='utf-8')
uni.dropna(inplace = True)
uni = uni.replace({r'\'': ''}, regex=True)
uni = uni.replace({r'\"': ''}, regex=True)
uni = uni.replace({r'\[\'': ''}, regex=True)
uni = uni.replace({r'\(': ''}, regex=True)
uni = uni.replace({r'\)': ''}, regex=True)
uni = uni.replace({r'\}': ''}, regex=True)
uni = uni.replace({r'\{': ''}, regex=True)
uni = uni.replace({r'\}': ''}, regex=True)
uni = uni.replace({r'\]': ''}, regex=True)
uni = uni.replace({r'\[': ''}, regex=True)
uni = uni.replace({r'\>': ''}, regex=True)
uni = uni.replace({r'\<': ''}, regex=True)
uni = uni.replace({r'\,': ''}, regex=True)
uni = uni.replace({r'\.': ''}, regex=True)
uni = uni.replace({r'\t': ''}, regex=True)
uni = uni.replace({r'\•': ''}, regex=True)
uni = uni.replace({r'\+': ''}, regex=True)
uni = uni.replace({r'\-': ''}, regex=True)
uni = uni.replace({r'\*': ''}, regex=True)
uni = uni.replace({r'\\': ''}, regex=True)    
uni = uni.replace({r'\/': ''}, regex=True)
uni = uni.replace({r'\:': ''}, regex=True)
uni = uni.replace({r'\;': ''}, regex=True)
uni = uni.replace({r'\r\n': ''}, regex=True)
uni = uni.replace({r'\n': ''}, regex=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mre] meaning test intput and expected output

Comment: I will dive into the data pipeline some more to see what is happening then come back with such.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using triple quotes, like this:

```
uni = uni.replace('''"['"''', '')
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately this didnt work. No error produced. I will dive into the data pipeline some more to see what is happening then come back.

Answer (score 0):

Apols for the delay, was badly ill. Anyway, here's the solution - it seems the regex was not working and a straight forward replace did the trick, here is the line that fixed this problem:

`l = [w.replace("[", "") for w in l]`

where l is a list of unigrams